# How to validate the SSL server certificate in twisted SSL client

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, twisted

How do I validate the SSL server certificates in my twisted SSL client?

I am very much beginner to the SSL, I have gone through the [twisted SSL tutorials](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.0.0/core/howto/ssl.html) but still I am unclear about some things.

My queries are:

- How should I validate the SSL server certificate using `twisted.internet.ssl` module,
- How `ssl.ClientContextFactory.getContext` method is useful while dealing with SSL,
- How can I tell twisted SSL client about the location of the public key file?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "validate".  Typically it is the underlying SSL implementation's job to do "validation".  Depending on what you mean, this may be done already, or you may need to write additional code to do it.

Comment: validate in the sense  checking the valid times ,host name and verifying the certificate.

Comment: Only host name checking is not already done for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Twisted 14.0, `optionsForClientTLS` is the best way to do this:

```
from twisted.internet.ssl import optionsForClientTLS
from twisted.internet.endpoints import SSL4ClientEndpoint

ctx = optionsForClientTLS(hostname=u"example.com")
endpoint = SSL4ClientEndpoint(reactor, host, port, ctx)
factory = ...
d = endpoint.connect(factory)
...
```

`optionsForClientTLS` takes other (optional) arguments as well which may also be useful.

Prior to Twisted 14.0, the process was a bit more involved:

After the connection is established and the SSL handshake has completed successfully (which means the certificate is currently valid based on its `notBefore` and `notAfter` values and that it is signed by a certificate authority certificate which you have indicated is trusted) you can get the certificate from the transport:

```
certificate = self.transport.getPeerCertificate()
```

The certificate is represented as a pyOpenSSL X509 instance.  It has a method you can use to retrieve the certificate's subject name:

```
subject_name = certificate.get_subject()
```

The subject name is a distinguished name, represented as a pyOpenSSL X509Name instance.  You can inspect its fields:

```
common_name = subject_name.commonName
```

This is a string, for example `"example.com"`.

If you need to inspect the `subjectAltName` instead (which it's likely you do), then you can find this information in the extensions of the certificate:

```
extensions = certificate.get_extensions()
```

This is a list of pyOpenSSL X509Extension instances.  You'll have to parse each one to find the `subjectAltName` and its value.

Comment: How to specify the ".pem" file that is , how can I tell to twisted ssl client  about my ".pem" file location.

Comment: A ".pem" file can contain any number of things.  I'm not sure what you're asking.  Does it contain the exact certificate the server is required to present?  Does it contain a certificate authority certificate which must have signed the server's certificate?  Does it contain a certificate chain?  Take a look at the pyOpenSSL Context documentation to see the APIs that exist for dealing with these requirements.

Comment: It contains the certificate chain.

Comment: That was a trick option, actually.  It doesn't make sense for clients to have a certificate chain file, unless you are *also* using a certificate on the client side to authenticate yourself to the server.

Comment: Is it possible to give me the working example(twisted ssl client)
which will compare the certificate which is received from the ssl server with the .pem file , and it does check the domain address to which it is connecting by using certificate which is received and checks the ,not after , not before.
Else please tell  me the way from where I can grasp there things

Comment: The answer shows you how to get the certificate sent by the server.  There is ample documentation explaining how to read the contents of a file.  What else is left to demonstrate?

Comment: Thank you ,

Instead of " subject_name = certificate.get_subject_name() " 
I have used "subject_name = certificate.get_subject()"